# Not able to connect to AWS through aws-sdk node js

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am new to AWS SDK and trying to follow the documents there. https://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/nodejs/ I am trying to create a bucket and upload some text file there. But I am getting the below mentioned error.

{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 52.216.206.51:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1104:14)
  message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT 52.216.206.51:443',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '52.216.206.51',
  port: 443,
  region: 'us-east-1',
  hostname:
   'node-sdk-sample-c58bc12a-70be-4578-9c18-1c815962653b.s3.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true,
  time: 20

I have tried giving credential in credential file under userid/.aws/credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = my cred...
aws_secret_access_key = my cred....
```

Also I have tried giving the credential in the code itself

```
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'my cred', secretAccessKey: 'my secret key', region: 'us-east-1'});

`// Load the SDK and UUID
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: '......', secretAccessKey: '.....', region: 'us-east-1'});

var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var bucketName = 'node-sdk-sample-' + uuid.v4();
var keyName = 'hello_world.txt';
s3.createBucket({Bucket: bucketName}, function() {
  var params = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: keyName, Body: 'Hello World!'};
  s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
      console.log(err)
    else
      console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName + "/" + keyName);
  });
});`
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you have allowed public access to the 443 port to this IP on AWS?

Comment: Not sure, how to check this?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this issue. The issue was related to proxy. I was trying to access this from behind a firewall. After configuring the proxy setting, I am able to connect to AWS.

```
var proxy = require('proxy-agent'); 
AWS.config.update({ httpOptions: { agent: proxy('ur proxy url') } });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk'); //require aws sdk library

var params = {
Bucket: awsBucketName,
Key: path + fileName,
Body: value.data
};

//s3 upload start
s3bucket.upload(params, (err, data) => {
if (err) {
  return reject(err);
}
return resolve(data.key);
});

//get signed url for downloading the uploaded file
const url = await s3bucket.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
  Bucket: awsBucketName,
  Key: key,
  Expires: 60*3
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some context and wording around your code - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer